# What does dot between words in CSS selectors mean, like"form.onepage"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just found the following code

```
form.onepage .row div {
padding-top: 4px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```

I understand the space in CSS selector means containing relationship and dot means selecting the class name. But What does "form.onepage" mean? There is no space before the dot....

I already read through the CSS selector reference on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp, but didn't find anything similiar.

Comment: It means "form element of the class 'onepage'"

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You should consider posting that as an answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

That means the class has been applied directly to that element.

`<form class="onepage">`

Likewise if you had a div `<div class="form onepage">` it would be `.form.onepage`.

This can be found in [the CSS selectors documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html).

Comment: sorry I still do not understand... do you have any manual about this feature? I looked through w3schools.com and didn't find anything on this.

Comment: @Jing He: If you do not understand this answer, it is very unlikely you will understand the manual. But here it is anyway: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors

Comment: Thank you a lot for the official manual !!! Actually I do understand the way it is explained in the official manual..... I guess the small typo in your previous answer confused me a little bit.... Actually I had read through the CSS selector reference in w3school.com before I asked this question, but they don't explain Element.Cass such kind of format